# Xcode not printing log/console messages. Shows a black debugger

Tags: c++, xcode, debugging, xcode5

I'm running an ipad project on XCode. My project builds and runs successfully. But the logger messages (cout/printf statements) are not getting printed. It was working fine. I don't know what I did.

This is how the debugger screen looks when the project is running.

[image: Debugger]

Help please..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works after restarting Xcode. Should be a glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Try to quit and restart the simulator.

If that still doesn't work then put a break point right before and after your print statements and see if your program is reaching that point.

If it doesn't reach the print statement, then put a break point in your viewDidLoad function and check if your program is running at all or not.